# Is there space being created when black holes merge?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes

Reason I ask.   I was reading a review of Richard Muller's book "  Now: The Physics of Time" and the idea is that new time as well as new space is being created when black holes merge.

I assume there is a huge super massive black hole after the merge but I was not aware that new space was being created. Does this consequence fall out of General Relativity perhaps ?

There is another question on stack exchange " What happens to information when black holes merge"?  But this is not what I am asking so unless there is another duplicate of mine somewhere I did not see it.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I wonder what a rigorous definition of "new space/time being created" would entail. Does the author state it anywhere?

Comment: you ask an excellent question.  He apparently wrote a book on this and devised an experiment to validate it by using the LIGO data but I don't know if anyone has actually taken it very seriously .  I guess that is part of my motivation for the question. I ordered the book from the library but t hey haven't bought it yet. I am on the waiting list.